# Nest like structure in Japanese Blueberry tree

Tags: trees, diseases, insects

I recently planted a Japanese Blueberry tree and it seems to be under a bit of stress(dropping leaves) from the transplant.

Today I noticed the nest structure shown in the images below. I am thinking it some kind of insect but wanted to see if anyone had more information and if its something that should be treated.

[image: japanese blueberry]

[image: japanese blueberry]